# Improve the Quality of Questions being Asked?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm wondering if there are any strategies we can employ to improve the quality of questions being asked? Here's an example of what is probably a good question but it's very difficult to tell without spending time reading his or her code:

- [**How to do this with new wp3 menus?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2720/how-to-do-this-with-new-wp3-menus)

Even a better title would help.  Thoughts?

-Mike